# python is not finding my installed modules in venv

Tags: python, pip, path, python-venv

This is a bit of a strange situation.

I am using python -m venv to create a virtual environment, everything runs fine, python is using the correct version when I test with sys.executable.

When I do pip list or python -m pip list streamlit (the app I am trying to use) comes up as an installed package, and in vsc it highlights as green, but when I try to run the code, I get a ModuleNotFoundError.

VSC is using the correct python interpreter from the venv and even highlights the module in green to say it has imported it.

I assuming this has something to do with path variables and where python is looking for packages?

But should a venv not automatically look within the site-packages folder in the venv?
[image: terminal showing streamlit installed and error]

[image: vsc showing highlighted module]

Comment: does it work if you try `python -m streamlit run test.py`?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, this was related to the PATH variables not specifying where to look for packages in virtual environments.

Setting a new path variable solved this issue.