# An existing module in venv is not recognized by Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

I am getting error for module dynamodb2 in boto but the module exists in my venv. Other modules in venv are recognized without any issues, only boto/dynamodb2 appears to have problem. I looked at similar issues posted on Stackoverflow such as  this one [python is not finding my installed modules in venv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70597521/python-is-not-finding-my-installed-modules-in-venv) but none matched my situation. Any ideas what may be wrong?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It turned out to be an issue with Pycharm version I was using. I encountered above problem while using PyCharm community version 2022.2.2. I had an older PC where I did not get the library import error above. The version used was community 2020.2.4. So I installed the same on my new PC the error went away. Still don't quite understand why newer Pycharm would give the error and older version will not.